# Transpose proxy model doesn't work in PyQt. Where is an error?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I tried to implement Transpose proxy model as it shown at [QtCentre's example](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Transpose_proxy_model) with PyQt 4.8 (PyQt 4.8, Python 2.7.8, Windows 7).

There is what I've done:

```
import os
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import uic


class TransposeProxyModel(QtGui.QAbstractProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, *argv):
        super(TransposeProxyModel, self).__init__(*argv)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        return self.index(sourceIndex.column(), sourceIndex.row())

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        return self.sourceModel().index(proxyIndex.column(), proxyIndex.row())

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        index = self.createIndex(row, column)
        print index.isValid()
        return index

    def parent(self, childIndex):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    # def flags(self, index):
    #   return self.sourceModel().flags(self.mapToSource(index))

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.sourceModel().columnCount()

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.sourceModel().rowCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        return self.sourceModel().data(self.mapToSource(index), role)


class PyQtApp(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *argv):
        super(PyQtApp, self).__init__(*argv)
        self.ui = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        uic.loadUi('window.ui', self.ui)

        # models
        self.mBase = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.mTransponsed = TransposeProxyModel()
        # self.mTransponsed = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.mTransponsed.setSourceModel(self.mBase)

        # widgets
        self.ui.baseView.setModel(self.mBase)
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.mBase)
        self.ui.transponsedView.setModel(self.mTransponsed)
        self.ui.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.on_loadButton_clicked)

    def run(self):
        self.ui.show()
        self.exec_()

    def on_loadButton_clicked(self):
        attributes = {'1st': '1val', '2nd': '2val'}
        for attr in attributes:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(attr)
            self.mBase.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = PyQtApp(sys.argv)
    i.run()
```

and UI file for testing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
  <class>MainWindow</class>
  <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
    <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>528</width>
        <height>446</height>
      </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="windowTitle">
      <string>MainWindow</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <item>
              <widget class="QListView" name="baseView"/>
            </item>
            <item>
              <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
                <item>
                  <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView"/>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <widget class="QTableView" name="transponsedView"/>
                </item>
              </layout>
            </item>
          </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2"/>
        </item>
        <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadButton">
            <property name="text">
              <string>PushButton</string>
            </property>
          </widget>
        </item>
      </layout>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
      <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>528</width>
          <height>21</height>
        </rect>
      </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  </widget>
  <resources/>
  <connections/>
</ui>
```

Three views are implemented in the example: `QListView` connected to the base `QStandardItemModel` (left), `QTableView` connected to the same base model (top right), and `QTableView` connected to my `TransposeModel` (bottom right).

The widget named `transposedView` (bottom right tableView) doesn't show anything. Other widgets work correctly.

After some investigation I've found that `createIndex()` method of the `TransposeModel` always returns invalid `QModelIndex`.

The example also was tested with Python 3.4, PyQt 5.3.

Where is the bug?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. No way is anyone going to download a random zip file from an unknown website.

Comment: It IS an MCVE. Unfortunately I can't post more than 2 links in a post now, so I had to pack my files in one.

Comment: let me clarify: please post the code *in the question itself* by clicking on the [edit] link, then using the code formatting button to make it display properly. In nearly all circumstances, including this one, a Stack Overflow question should be *self-contained*, no external links to code or data should be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. DOne.Actually, I don't think it got more clear now though...

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar with a QSqlTableModel, having to transpose the data in the final QTableView, and have made it work. I believe that the main problem lies in the fact that you are not actually fetching the data from the source model.

The following code works for me:

```
class TransposeModel(QtGui.QAbstractProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, sourceModel):
        super(TransposeModel, self).__init__()
        self.setSourceModel(sourceModel)

    def setSourceModel(self, sourceModel):
        self._sourceModel = sourceModel
        QtGui.QAbstractProxyModel.setSourceModel(self, sourceModel)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        return self.index(sourceIndex.column(), sourceIndex.row())

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        return self._sourceModel.index(proxyIndex.column(), proxyIndex.row())

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return self._sourceModel.columnCount(parent)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self._sourceModel.rowCount(parent)

    def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            return self._sourceModel.data(self.mapFromSource(index), role)
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return self._sourceModel.headerData(section, QtCore.Qt.Vertical, role)
        else:
            return self._sourceModel.headerData(section, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, role)
```